# Do you contact the search chair before applying for a position?

Tags: faculty-application

In some job advertisements, the chair of search committee is named for informal inquiries.

I contacted them with a brief resume, asking if they are interested in my line of experiences or not. They simply replied me "send the application, we will review it".

I am curious what is informal inquiries? What should/can I ask?

In general, is it a bad idea to contact the search people before applying, when I am serious about a specific position? (most applications are shot in the dark, but we are extremely interested in some positions)

Comment: Asking "Do I have a chance" isn't likely to produce a useful answer since the search committee can't prejudge the candidates.  If you ask something like "Are you looking for someone in area X or would area Y be a better fit for your department?"  then the search committee chair might be able to give you a helpful response.

Answer (score 2):

In general, it is a good idea to contact people you are applying to. They might say that they are looking for someone with your background (or with another).

But if they write

> send the application, we will review it

just do it. There is no shortcut.

Don't expect that they will write how likely are you to get accepted - even forgetting about the legal things, they don't what are the other applicants.